# Keep z-index when dragging in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, drag-and-drop, easeljs

I've got interactive items on my canvas and a PNG overlay on top.
When I drag the interactive items, it moves to the top.
How can I keep them below the overlay?

I know I can do this using a container, but I've been told that containers have quite a bit of overhead so I was wondering if there was another method at all?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Containers add a little overhead -- and are not recommended to hold a single item. But their overhead is nominal in the grand scheme of things. I know that is in the documentation, but I wouldn't worry about it too much

Comment: The drag and drop model in EaselJS does not re-order anything. Are you manually calling `addChild` or something? I believe the dragging demo in EaselJS does this on purpose to bring the dragging item to the top. Specifically line 54 of this demo: http://createjs.com/demos/easeljs/draganddrop -- just remove that line if you based your work off of this demo.

Comment: Yip...that was it! Thanks :-)